# build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details. BUILD FAILED

Tags: java, tomcat7, netbeans-7.3

> Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, NetBeans 7.3.1, Tomcat 7.0.34

My project was working fine, and suddenly I get this `error`:

```
/my/project's/path/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED
```

I researched for a week, and I tried everything: checked the database `username` and `password`, installed `tomcat` admin, cleared netbeans cache, etc.

I looked int the `tomcat logs` and the only thing suspicious that I found was in the `localhost_access_log.(date).log` file:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:43 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:43 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:43 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:43 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:43 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:43 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:43 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 985
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:46 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 985
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:49 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 985
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:52 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 985
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:52 +0300] "GET /Test/service/info/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20468
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:55 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 985
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:55 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 985
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:40:58 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 985
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:01 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 985
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:04 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 985
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:07 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 985
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:07 +0300] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext3726028026992785425.xml&path=/Test HTTP/1.1" 404 989
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:10 +0300] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext3726028026992785425.xml&path=/Test HTTP/1.1" 404 989
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:13 +0300] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext3726028026992785425.xml&path=/Test HTTP/1.1" 404 989
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:16 +0300] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext3726028026992785425.xml&path=/Test HTTP/1.1" 404 989
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:19 +0300] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext3726028026992785425.xml&path=/Test HTTP/1.1" 404 989
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:22 +0300] "GET /Test/service/info/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20468
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:31 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:31 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:41:32 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I see a lot of 404 errors.

Oh, and the browser doesn't start when I run the application. But that is  probably happening because the module is not deployed.

Any ideas?

Catalina.2016-06-02.log:

```
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /home/petre/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64:/home/petre/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8443"]
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:26 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1023 ms
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/petre/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/conf/Catalina/localhost/VReports.xml
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/petre/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/conf/Catalina/localhost/HafasPassengerInfo.xml
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:31 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  server.resource
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:31 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class server.resource.VJResource
  class server.resource.GFPSResource
  class server.resource.CResource
  class server.resource.SResource
  class server.resource.TRPIResource
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:31 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:31 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.13 06/29/2012 05:14 PM'
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/petre/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/manager
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/petre/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/docs
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/petre/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/examples
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/petre/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/ROOT
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/petre/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/host-manager
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8443"]
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
Jun 02, 2016 2:10:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6592 ms
```

Comment: please, see catalina.out file, might be possible there were clear error message present.

Comment: Show us the catalina.out

Comment: I added the catalina-2016-06-02.log to the description above. I don't have any catalina.out in tomcat/logs.

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner of the directory of Tomcat. On Linux or BSD do this:

chown -R username /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/

*check in which path to the directory's Tomcat on your distro

Answer (score 0):

if you are deleting any servlet from your project then just look out your web.xml file,
 `<servlet></servlet>` 
properly close or not..? 
check for this in your web.xml definitely it is present 
    `<servlet>
        <servlet-class/>
    </servlet>`
just remove this code.then run your project.